# Horizontal center a FlexTable in a parent FlowPanel?

Tags: gwt

I've created a FlexTable, and I want to center it horizontally within a parent FlowPanel, like:

```
FlexTable ft = new FlexTable();
ft.add(0, 0, new Label());
ft.add(0, 1, new Orange());
ft.add(0, 2, new Label());

FlowPanel parent = new FlowPanel();
parent.add(ft); // how can I horizontally center the table in this div?
```

The content of the table is narrower than the parent FlowPanel (which is width:auto, the whole width of the browser), but the table is left-aligned right now,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all? Which version of GWT are you using? The reason am asking this question, there is no method in FlexTable that is similar to add (int, int, Widget ) you have used in the [latest version](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html).

However, you can use the following code.

```
    FlexTable ft = new FlexTable();
    ft.setWidget(0, 0, new Label("a"));
    ft.setWidget(0, 1, new Label("b"));
    ft.setWidget(0, 2, new Label("c"));

    FlowPanel parent = new FlowPanel();
    parent.setSize("100%", "100%");
    parent.add(ft);
    parent.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("TextAlign", "center");
    // If you are using Firefox : 
    //parent.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("TextAlign", "-moz-center");
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(parent);
```

If you dont't wish to mention the style in the java code, you can always use CSS like

```
parent.addStyleName("myStyle");
```

In CSS

```
.myStyle{
text-align : center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

```
parent.getElement().getStyle().setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);
```

or

```
ft.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("margin", "0 auto");
```

You can use CSS styles instead, of course.

Comment: There is no method such as `setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);`. Reference http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html

Comment: @Abhijith  Of course, there is! http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#setTextAlign(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.TextAlign)